# Vagrant user doesn't have root permissions even with sudo?

Tags: docker, vagrant

Disclaimer: I'm looking for solutions that are programmatic. i.e. `vagrant up` and everything works without any special configuration on the end-user's machine. In other words, all the config should be done on my part in the Vagrantfile, docker-compose, provisioning scripts, etc.

---

Update: I believe, I've located a more primitive manifestation of this problem. If I `mkdir somedir` I get a directory owned by my user. If I then `sudo mkdir someotherdir`, it's owned by root. But inside `vagrant ssh` the same two commands always give a directory owned by vagrant and never root. How can this be worked around?

---

I am trying to get a nextcloud/nginx/mariadb/redis arrangement running with each service inside its own Docker container. The whole thing should be contained inside a virtual machine set up through Vagrant.

Here's my project directory (located someplace inside my home folder):

```
-Vagrantfile
-bootstrap.sh
-nextc/
|-docker-compose.yml
|-nginx.conf
```

If I cd into `nextc/` and run `docker-compose up`, a directory called `persist` is created in the root of the project directory (see the compose file below for details).

```
ls -l

...
drwxr-xr-x 5 root     root      4096 авг 12 19:06 persist
...
```

The `persist` contains all stateful stuff, like the configs of nextcloud, database files, and is created due to the docker compose file below:

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ../persist/db/:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true

  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes: 
      - ../persist/redis/:/data
    expose: 
      - 6379
    restart: always

  app:
    image: nextcloud:fpm
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ../persist/nextcloud/:/var/www/html
    restart: always

  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    links:
      - app
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    volumes_from:
      - app
    restart: always
```

Importantly, it is created as belonging to the root user, while some subdirectories inside there belong either to www-data or root. All works as expected and I can access nextcloud over localhost:8081.

Next I set up my `Vagrantfile` as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8081, host: 8080
end
```

and `bootstrap.sh` is

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y \
     apt-transport-https \
     ca-certificates \
     curl \
     software-properties-common

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg > key
sudo apt-key add - < key
rm key

sudo add-apt-repository \
     "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
      $(lsb_release -cs) \
      stable"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce

sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

cd /vagrant/nextc

sudo docker-compose up -d
```

Since this didn't work as expected, I ssh'd into the vagrant machine and had a look at the output of `docker-compose up`.

It was `MariaDB` complaining: many error messages such as

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0': Operation not permitted
```

or

```
mkdir cannot create directory '/var/lib/mysql//mysql' permission denied
```

The `persist` directory is created not as belonging to `root`, but belonging to Vagrant (viewed inside the VM) or belonging to my user (as seen from the host machine). Clearly this seems to be some kind of permissions issue.

How can I make sure that Vagrant works the same as the host machine?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and fixed it by using vagrant reload, i don't know what caused it but it happened several times to me.